# Set the time for connection's life in Golang

Tags: go, tcp

I am a novice in golang and I am writing a client-server application through the TCP protocol. I need to make a temporary connection, which will close after a couple of seconds. I don't understand how to do that.
I have a such function, which creates a connection and waits for gob data:

```
    func net_AcceptAppsList(timesleep time.Duration) {
        ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+conf.PORT)
        CheckError(err)
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        CheckError(err)
        dec := gob.NewDecoder(conn)
        pack := map[string]string{}
        err = dec.Decode(&pack)
        fmt.Println("Message:", pack)
        conn.Close()
}
```

I need to make this function to wait for data for only some seconds - not forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SetDeadline` or `SetReadDeadline`

From the [`net.Conn` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn)

```
    // SetDeadline sets the read and write deadlines associated
    // with the connection. It is equivalent to calling both
    // SetReadDeadline and SetWriteDeadline.
    //
    // A deadline is an absolute time after which I/O operations
    // fail with a timeout (see type Error) instead of
    // blocking. The deadline applies to all future I/O, not just
    // the immediately following call to Read or Write.
    //
    // An idle timeout can be implemented by repeatedly extending
    // the deadline after successful Read or Write calls.
    //
    // A zero value for t means I/O operations will not time out.
    SetDeadline(t time.Time) error

    // SetReadDeadline sets the deadline for future Read calls.
    // A zero value for t means Read will not time out.
    SetReadDeadline(t time.Time) error

    // SetWriteDeadline sets the deadline for future Write calls.
    // Even if write times out, it may return n > 0, indicating that
    // some of the data was successfully written.
    // A zero value for t means Write will not time out.
    SetWriteDeadline(t time.Time) error
```

If you want the Accept call to timeout, you can use the [`TCPListener.SetDeadline`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPListener.SetDeadline) method.

```
ln.(*net.TCPListener).SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second))
```

Optionally, you could have a timer call `Close()` or `CloseRead()` on the connection, or `Close()` on the net.Listener, but that won't leave you with the cleaner timeout error.

Comment: No, this is not what I want. Of caourse I saw this functions and I'll never ask this question if these functions was what I want. This functions just set the timeout of read or write or both operations! But if there is no any of it, then nothing happens.

Comment: @IgniSerpens: then please show an example of what you need. The `Decode` call is going to do a `Read` on the connection, so this will cause `Decode` to return after the Deadline expires.

Comment: We need to make a timeout for existing of the connection itself.

Comment: but this Decode will never be executed until we have someone who connects to our socket.

Comment: You say in the question that you are making a connection, so one would assume it's been accepted and you're in the `Decode` method. If you want `Accept` to timeout, use `SetDeadline` on the `TCPListener`.

Comment: Oh, thats what I want! Thanks! It works! Seems standart net.Listener does not have this method, but net.TCPListener does.

Answer (score 0):

As @JimB said in comments, we need to use another listener - net.TCPListener, which have method SetDeadline, setting the connection lifetime, while the standart net.Listener doesn't have it.